# Why can't I access Session data that exists before the return statement in NextJs page

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Trying to understand how this works.

I have a Session present in NextJS.  I can access that inside the page view no problem.

But If I try to access any of that data before the return statement, it comes back undefined, even though the variables are in the page when it renders.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Sample code from a page

```js
const { data: session } = useSession();

if(session) { // Never runs, always evaluates as false
  console.log("USER ID : " + session.userId); 
}
console.log("USER ID : " + session?.userId); // Undefined
// @ts-ignore
if(session) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="min-h-full">
        <nav className="bg-fadedFadedPurple">
          <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16 w-full">
              <div className="flex items-center w-full h-full">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
/*perfectly fine*/  <Link className="hover:cursor-pointer" href={`/app/${session.userId}/dashboard`}>
```

Comment: Are you certain the value of `session?.userId` comes back as `undefined` in the browser's console?

Comment: 100%, where it is marked undefined it returns undefined 100%

Comment: With the code you provided it seems that it's not really possible to happen. Maybe you could make some quick repro on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Not sure I can set up something to mirror a nextJs environment on there but I will see if I can duplicate this there.

Comment: Would it make sense to put it inside of a useEffect hook? I had to do this with Nextjs to get the query Params on a page refresh because they were undefined

Comment: @AWebb I don't know, that is why I am asking.  Does that work? Can you provide a working example and explain why I have to use that? That is what I am looking for and hence the bounty.  I don't just need a fix, I need to understand why this won't give access to its values until I am in the return statement. Or, the case of your example, why I would need to put it inside there for it work.

Comment: According to the docs I don't think it should be behaving that way. You should verify your `[...nextauth].js/ts` logic and have you tried testing something like [this](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#frontend---add-react-hook)? If you can't get something working like that then the problem is not in the component.

Comment: @AWebb in that example you linked to all the session data is coming in inside the return (except the check, which works in my code too).  Which works in mine as well.  Specifically I am asking why I cannot access it before that.  But I do have the session data in the view like that, and the `if(session)` check returns true, but if I try to log out some data before that it comes back undefined, which makes no sense to me and I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: @AWebb. Notice where exactly in my code the `undefined` is.  After I create the session variable, but before the `if(session)` check.  specifically that spot it is undefined which is confusing to me.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. What happens when you do something like this?

const { data: session } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [session]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246702/discussion-between-a-webb-and-rockwell-rice).

Comment: If you can see the expected value of `session.userId` in the DOM on the link where it's used then it's just not possible that the `console.log` would not print the right value when it gets set. Are you sure you're not looking at the terminal rather than in the browser's console for the log output?

Comment: 100%. I can't say this enough, 100% it logs out undefined.  100%.

Comment: Have you looked at the post-JSX code?

Comment: @user3840170 I haven't.  I am just trying to understand how this works.  I am being asked over and over why we "can't do this" and I don't really know what to say, so I posted this question trying to get an authoritative response on why I can run that code which "looks" like it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useSession in Next.js is only defined after an initial loading state see: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#example-1

you are trying to check the session before this loading state so it is undefined and does not hit your conditions.

Later when it is rendering in your page the hook gets the session as its past
the initial loading state

this is what you are trying to do, but require a callback to when the state is loaded

```
     const session = useSession({
            required: true,
            onUnauthenticated() {
            // The user is not authenticated, handle it here.
            },
        })

        if (status === "loading") {
            //if(session) { //this is your Undefined
            console.log("USER ID : " + session?.userId); 
            //}
            return "Loading or not authenticated..."
        }
        //if(session) { // this is if the session has been loaded
          console.log("USER ID : " + session.userId); 
        //}

        return "User is logged in"
    }
```

further if you want the session youll have to await a call

```
   const session = await getSession()
```

as per the documentation
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession

hope this helps you understand why your code isnt working